# Can i make inner static class as a singleton

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-sqlite

I am making inner static class as a singleton to avoid    A SQLiteConnection object for database 'db' was leaked! Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

**I can close the `mDb.close`  after db transactions using `mDb` instance(in case of just static class) ,**

I want to know is it right way to make inner static class as a singleton in a constructor of outer class ??

```
  private ImageDb mDb;

        public class SavedImages extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
             public SavedImages(Activity context) {
                    ImageDb.moveFromCacheDirectoryIfNecessary(context);
                    mDb = ImageDb.getInstance(context);

                }


    static class ImageDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
        final static String DB_NAME = "wallpaper_images.db";
        final static String TABLE_NAME = "wallpaper_images";
        final static String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        final static String COLUMN_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_FILENAME = "image_thumbnail";
        final static String COLUMN_IMAGE_FILENAME = "image";

        //Context mContext;

        private static ImageDb mImageDb;

    public static ImageDb getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mImageDb == null) {
            mImageDb = new ImageDb(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mImageDb;
    }


    private ImageDb(Context context) {
        super(context, context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath(), null, DB_VERSION);
         }

        public static void moveFromCacheDirectoryIfNecessary(Context context) {
           //static method
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
   //oncreate db
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          //onupgrade db
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: [`static inner`is a contradiction in terms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

A correct way to implement this is to have a file with a class, named A

```
public class A {
  private static class SingletoneHolder {
    //here you declare the instance of what you want
  }

  public static YourInstance getInstance(){
    return YourInstance;
  }
}
```

This way you access to the instance of this class whenever you want inside your app.

Answer (score -1):

```
class TestOuter2{  

    static int data=30;  

    static class Inner{  
        static void msg() {
            System.out.println("data is "+data);
        }  
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        TestOuter2.Inner.msg();//no need to create the instance of static nested class  
    }  

}
```